# After an update, Ubuntu would not let me login. My user name pops up but when I press Enter the screen goes black forever

Tags: boot

Dell laptop running Ubuntu version 22.04; update ran on Friday - Oct. 13

Comment: Did you try the "recovery" option from the grub menu?  Welcome to Askubuntu.  What kind of hardware do you have?  If you installed proprietary video drivers, how did you do that?  Add information to your original posting rather than answer in comments.

Comment: What packages did you update before Ubuntu would not let you login?